# ADT import of android.media cannot be resolved

Tags: android, adt

i try create my first android application for android 2.1 api level 7 in ADT. I wrote the following line to the default view and eclipse says, that android.media cannot be resolved:

```
import android.media;
```

how come, that this doesn't work?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot `import android.media;` because it is a package, try using:

```
import android.media.*;
```

or

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer; // if you want to import MediaPlayer
import android.media.Ringtone;    // if you want to import Ringtone
```

Comment: Yep. OP's code was looking for the class `media` in the package `android`.